# Error with htaccess redirecting to php file, and php outputting file when user has permission

Tags: php, file, .htaccess

This seems like a strange one to me; I have a directory of files that are dynamically uploaded and I need to check permission first before a user can open that file so I added htaccess to the directory with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../../get_file.php [QSA]
```

Then I check in php for permission and if the user has permission, I am trying to serve the user the file like so:

```
//serve file back to user
$full_file_name = 'uploads/conversation_attachments/'.$file_name;
$filesize = filesize($full_file_name);
header("Content-length: ".$filesize);
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$full_file_name.";");
readfile($full_file_name);
```

It spits back 'a' file but not 'the' file. So instead of getting the file "rYMmfk3j9BSrjaRC.pdf" with the $file_name="rYMmfk3j9BSrjaRC.pdf" I am getting a file called "uploads_conversation_attachments_rYMmfk3j9BSrjaRC.pdf". Somehow it is replacing the slashes with underscores it seems.

Any one have any ideas why this is happening? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file_name};");
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

don't output any server-side path data to the client - it's useless information. The server-side path is extremely unlikely to exist on the client, and browsers won't honor it anyways, otherwise malicious servers could try to scribble on any arbitrary file on the client machine.

Comment: Ah right, that works perfect! I was going on the faulty assumption that the content disposition was also needed to tell the server where the file is. Thanks very much, I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Nope. content-disposition is instructions for the client. "Here's some content, and here's how you should dispose of it"